# Padding the output of a list of 2d arrays given by tf.split efficiently

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tf.keras

I am trying to make a physics inspired machine learning model, but I am coming across a strange problem while writing the cost function.

The network takes in a vector of length N and outputs a vector of length N, so in essence a multidimensional regression problem.

The issue is that irregular subsets of this vector need to mantain a norm of 1, which is part of the cost function. That is to say, the output of the ML model needs to split the vector and take the norm of each split section.
Let's say the vector is of length 100, this is split into sub-tensors of length
50 30 25 5.
the problem is that it is also a time series, so actually we have an output list of these shapes:
[(100,50) (100,30) (100,25) (100,5)].
To efficiently compute the norm without a loop I need to pad the second axis with 0's so that the tensors can be combined and the norms computed in one loop, but this requires an efficient way to transform this into
[(100,50), (100,50), (100,50), (100,50)] so that I can stack the dataframes and run the norm computation without a loop.

It might be that I am overthinking it and that a loop is fine.

At the moment I have this, where the inputs are of shape (100,100) and norm_list contains the lengths of the parts that have to have the norm computed. The reason for the strange splitting is because the actual values are complex, but represented as pairs of reals.

```
def prop_loss_full(y_true,y_pred):
    y_truer, y_truec = f2rr_full(y_true)
    y_predr, y_predc = f2rr_full(y_pred)
    diff = math_ops.squared_difference(y_pred,y_true)
    split_real = tf.split(y_predr,norm_list,1)
    split_imag = tf.split(y_predc,norm_list,1)
    norm = math_ops.reduce_sum((math_ops.square(split_real[0])+math_ops.square(split_imag[0])),axis=1)

    for i in range(1,len(split_real)):
        norm+=math_ops.reduce_sum((math_ops.square(split_real[i])+math_ops.square(split_imag[i])),axis=1)

    return norm+ks.MSE(y_true, y_pred)
prop_loss_full(data,data)
```

Any help would be appreciated! When I use tf.pad_sequence I get an error - I assume it doesn't like seuqences of 2d tensors. I have looked far and wide, including ragged tensors and other such features, but have not managed to get them to work.

Comment: Looking at the docs, `tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences` shoud work. Did you call it on the whole sequence `[(100,50) (100,30) (100,25) (100,5)]` or just parts of it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mhenning, yeah, that's what I thought as well, I did call it on the whole sequence at once and it wouldn't work, although it did work if I passed a sequence of one slice, i.e.```[(50) (30) (25) (5)]```. At this point, I am just using a loop and computing the norms individually on each subtensor in the list. It's fine for these sizes, but I worry about whether it will scale. Then again, perhaps I can postpone this problem to when it actually becomes a problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `pad_sequences` if you transpose your data first:

```
# random data in the same shape as yours
x = [tf.random.uniform((100, x)) for x in [50, 30, 25]]  # shape: [(100, 50), (100, 30), (100, 25)]

x = [tf.transpose(x_) for x_ in x]  # shape: [(50, 100), (30, 100), (25, 100)]
x = tf.keras.utils.pad_sequences(x)  # shape: tensor(3, 50, 100)
x = tf.transpose(x, [0, 2, 1])  # shape: tensor(3, 100, 50)
```

You still have a loop for the transpose operation of the data, but it should still be faster than using the loop over the subtensors.

Comment: Thanks! This worked really nicely actually, much faster than my original approach - I ended up using this and experimenting with building a ragged tensor directly. But it turns out the fastest way was to move away from a sequential model into a functional one with multiple outputs doing the split and then computing an individual loss function for each.

Comment: I'm glad I cold help. If you're satisfied with the answer, it would be great if you could accept it as an anwer.

Comment: Done, and of course! I still need to get used to how this system works.